# Do any big companies use Infopath forms?

Tags: infopath

Conceptually it is a great tool, but are there really any big commercial companies that use infopath ? I have seen a couple of case studies but not found any useful lists that describe big commercial ventures that use Infopath in a significant way.

Comment: Theoretically Infopath and sharepoint etc are great apps/frameworks. In reality, they suck. They really really suck.

Answer (score 2):

Likely those adopting InfoPath are into it for its SharePoint integration.

See [Microsoft's InfoPath case studies](http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Search_Results.aspx?Type=1&ProTaxID=1778).

- Del Monte Foods
- Energizer
- Bank of America
- Colorado Bureau of Investigation
- Grant Thornton LLP
- Tampa Police Department
- Microsoft Global Security
- Kingdom of Jordan Water Ministry

Answer (score 0):

I did developed and deployed into production several large applications using InfoPath. It's a nice platform to develop and very easy to extract information, even more when used with Sharepoint and/or Forms Services.

Main concern about this tool is related to licensing costs.